# Class field theory for $\mathbb{Q}_p$

Tags: number-theory, class-field-theory

Let $K$ be a local field and fix an algebraic closure $\bar{K}$. Local class field theory says basically that $L\mapsto N_{L/K}(L^\times)$ is a order-reversing bijection between the finite abelian extensions of $K$ contained in $\bar{K}$ and the subgroups of $K^\times$ with finite index.

Possibly, the simplest case is that of $K=\mathbb{Q}_p$, for $p>2$. I've calculated that
$$\mathbb{Q}_p^\times \cong \mathbb{Z}_p\times \mathbb{Z}/(p-1)\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$$
and so it should be possible to determine all its finite-index subgroups and possibly classify the finite abelian extensions of $\mathbb{Q}_p$, even if we can't describe those extensions explicitly (which I presume is possible using Lubin-Tate theory, but that's not exactly the point of my question).

How could we apply such a procedure?

Comment: [Local Kronecker--Weber Theorem](https://math.mit.edu/classes/18.785/2019fa/LectureNotes20.pdf) says that every finite abelian extension of $\Bbb Q_p$ is contained in some $\Bbb Q_p(\zeta_m)$; if $m$ is coprime to $p$ then it is unramified, and if $m$ is a power of $p$ then it is totally ramified.

Comment: Chapter V of [Local Fields by Serre](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387904245) contains calculations about the norm groups in various cases.

Comment: Proposition 3 says that for the case $m = p^f - 1$, the corresponding norm group is $\Bbb Z_p \times \Bbb Z/(p-1)\Bbb Z \times f\Bbb Z$ (so the quotient is $\Bbb Z/f\Bbb Z$).

Comment: I suspect that the norm group for the case $m = p^n$ is $p^{n-1} \Bbb Z_p \times \{1\} \times \Bbb Z$.

Comment: Your question is a bit broad, try being more specific given the comments and answer.

Comment: I think I wasn't very clear. My question boils down to the following: can we determine explicitly the finite-index subgroups of $\mathbb{Q}_p^\times$?

Answer (score 1):

$$N(\Bbb{Q}_p(\zeta_{p^n}\zeta_{p^f-1})^\times)=p^{f\Bbb{Z}} (\Bbb{Z}_p^{\times})^{p^{n-1}(p-1)}$$
Then send $p^r a\in p^\Bbb{Z}\Bbb{Z}_p^\times$ to the automorphism $$\zeta_{p^n}\zeta_{p^f-1}\to \zeta_{p^n}^a\zeta_{p^f-1}^{p^r}$$ This is your isomorphism $$\Bbb{Q}_p^\times/N(\Bbb{Q}_p(\zeta_{p^n}\zeta_{p^f-1})^\times)\to Gal(\Bbb{Q}_p(\zeta_{p^n}\zeta_{p^f-1})/\Bbb{Q}_p)$$
For each subgroup $H'$ of the LHS you get a subgroup $H$ of the RHS and an abelian extension $$K_H=\Bbb{Q}_p(\zeta_{p^n}\zeta_{p^f-1})^H=\Bbb{Q}_p(\{\sum_{\sigma \in H} \sigma((\zeta_{p^n}\zeta_{p^f-1}))^j),j<p^{n-1}(p-1)f\})$$
with norm group $H'$.

Comment: Dear @reuns, what does $p^\mathbb{Z}$ means? And why are you considering $\mathbb{Q}_p(\zeta_{p^n}\zeta_{p^f-1})$?

Comment: The subgroup of $\Bbb{Q}_p^\times$ generated by $p$. I am considering all the cyclotomic extensions because they contain all the abelian extensions.

Comment: that's nice! I certainly feel that a have a better understanding now. Do you know if we can determine the finite-index subgroups of $\mathbb{Q}_p^\times$?